# arrays of type char and rand function

Tags: c++, arrays

I could not phrase the question properly but here it goes:
 I want to create a random `password` and that password contains special characters,letter and numbers
so i have decided the ASCII range and assigned them to the password array
everything works properly but when i print it out to the console weird characters pop up that were not in the range.

```
int main(){
    srand(time(nullptr));
    char password[15];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        password[i] = (rand() % 89) + 33;

    }
    cout << password << endl;
return 0;
}
```

that is the code that causes problem but when i assign the last element to be null value it works properly.
is it because when you create a c type string the last index should always be null?

Comment: password[i-1] = '\0'; 
like so after the for loop which is the same for 14.
@FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: The question is more or less for myself not trying to use that in a real word scenario.@Ðаn

Comment: "...but when i assign the last element to be null value it works properly." You drew no conclusions from that? [Perhaps this will help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

Comment: i wanted to know where all the other characters comes i defined an array size of 15 but there were like 20 or more characters on the screen.
i drew a conclusion from that and was wanting a well put answer.
thanks! @WhozCraig

Comment: that is what i was looking for! thank you and could you make it an answer?
@FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: The moment you send a `char[]` to `std::cout` without an affirmed terminator, you invoke *undefined behavior*. With that, there is no longer a definitive reason for what transpires. It could be worse. It could have seemingly *worked* and you walked away thinking all was well, only to have it crash and burn on a prof's machine, or even worse, a *customer's*.

Comment: I will consider using  'std::string' from now on.@WhozCraig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string must finish with a string terminator, or it isn't a string. If you omit the terminator, there is no way to know how long the string is. One might assume that since `password` is `const char[15]` that the size could be deduced, but in practice, just about everything that works with strings will treat it as a pointer and iterate until a null terminator is found. Since you don't have one, they will iterate past the end of your buffer leading to undefined behavior. Consider using `std::string` to avoid these concerns. See [Null-terminated byte strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte).